# get ip of a socket without client connecting to it C++ BOOST LIBRARY

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I am trying to save the server's IP without a client connecting to the server. The server is iterative synchronous and awaits for clients to connect. As I mentioned above I need to save the IP before the clients start connecting to the server. The commented out code is actually getting the address of the endpoint of the socket. I don't expect someone to write code but maybe to explain me where I am wrong... so here is my code:

```
string ds_IP;
```

DS::DS(void)
{

cout << "Data Server is UP!" << endl;

`boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1));




for (;;)
{   
    tcp::socket incoming(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(incoming);

    /*//identify IP
    tcp::endpoint remote = incoming.remote_endpoint();
    boost::asio::ip::address remote_address = remote.address();
    ds_IP = remote_address.to_string();

    cout << ds_IP << endl;*/
    cout << "Client is Connected" << endl;
}`

}

Comment: Your acceptor is set up to listen for connections on any interface (since you passed `tcp::v4()` as the local endpoint. Therefore, there's no way to know what local endpoint a client will connect to until the connection is made.

Comment: but since both client and server are running from my device it means that server will use the localhost IP address so for now I guess it would be fine to set that as the acceptor's endpoint and the only difference between server instances will be the port number. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: It depends upon context. Do you want to share the connectivity ability across a network? Printing "127.0.0.1:12345" will not allow others to connect to you.

Comment: So that address is not the address of the server?

Comment: It is the *local* address of the server. Clients running in the same host can use it to connect. Clients running in other hosts cannot. As stated, your question doesn't make sense. You need the public IP address *of the server.* The part about getting it from the listening socket is just an incorrect assumption on your part. You can get it via the DNS APIs.